# Jquery ajax parsing error for json

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am trying to send some data using php and jquery ajax using json datatype method.
Here is my code:

```
$("#username").on("keyup change keypress", function () {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST", // method send from ajax to server
        url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + "admin/admins/user_exists",
        data: {
            username: username
        },// Specifies data to be sent to the server
        cache: false, // A Boolean value indicating whether the browser should cache the requested pages. Default is true
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json', // The data type expected of the server response.
        success: function (response_data_from_server) {

            for (var key in response_data_from_server)
                var result = response_data_from_server[key] + ""; // JSON parser

            if (result == 'true') {
                console.log("---------------- in true");
                $("#username_alert").text("ERROR");
                $('#username_alert').removeClass("alert-success");
                $("#username_alert").css("visibility", "visible");

            }
            else {
                if (result == 'false') {
                    console.log("---------------- in false");
                    $("#username_alert").text("NO ERROR");
                    $("#username_alert").css("visibility", "visible");
                    $('#username_alert').addClass("alert-success");
                }
                else {
                    if (result == 'empty') {
                        console.log("---------------- in empty");
                        $("#username_alert").text("ERROR");
                        $("#username_alert").css("visibility", "visible");
                        $('#username_alert').removeClass("alert-success");
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

and it always goes to an error function. The error that I receive is the following:

> parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿ {}

My url location is correct and is indeed returning the correct json format. Here is my php code:

```
public function user_exists()
      {
          $username = $this->input->post("username");
          $is_exists = "false";
          $this->load->database();
          if ($username != "")
          {
              $rows = $this->db->query("
                                        SELECT * FROM `admins` WHERE `username` = '" . $username . "'
        ")->num_rows();
              if ($rows > 0)
              {
                  $is_exists = "true";   
              }
              else 
              {
                  $is_exists = "false";
              }
          }
          else
          {
              $is_exists = "empty";
          }
          $arr = array ('result' => $is_exists );
          $response = json_encode($arr);
          echo $response;

      }
```

I've debugged it million times, the firebug sees the response as correct and expected json, however the client side seems to refuse to get it as a json respone, for what I believe.

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: can you post json example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $response;
```

Maybe you could use "header('Content-type: application/json');" before "echo"

Comment: Just for reference: if you have
header("Content-type: application/x-javascript; charset=UTF-8");
you are mistaken. You need to correct it as:
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: @salihcenap php json_encode not only encodes the array to json, but also does encode the UTF8 characters. so you don't need to send charset, i think.